# Match array with JSON

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have a JSON array (causesoferror):

```
[
  { 
  "code" : "001",
  "descr" : "Descr001",
  "wheretocheck" : "Where001",
  "measurestobetaken" : "Measure001"
  },
  {
  "code" : "002",
  "descr" : "Descr002",
  "wheretocheck" : "Where002",
  "measurestobetaken" : "Measure002"
  },
  {
  "code" : "003",
  "descr" : "Descr003",
  "wheretocheck" : "Where003",
  "measurestobetaken" : "Measure003"
  },
  {
   ETC,ETC,ETC   
  },
  {
  "code" : "400",
  "descr" : "Descr400",
  "wheretocheck" : "Where400",
  "measurestobetaken" : "Measure400"
  }
]
```

And an array with some codes (gbrumdatacoesplit):
[image]

I need to match the value of the second one (the one with just the numbers) with the first one and create a new object, something like:

```
[
      { 
      "code" : "004",
      "descr" : "Descr004",
      "wheretocheck" : "Where004",
      "measurestobetaken" : "Measure004"
      },
      {
      "code" : "101",
      "descr" : "Descr101",
      "wheretocheck" : "Where101",
      "measurestobetaken" : "Measure101"
      },
      {
      "code" : "102",
      "descr" : "Descr102",
      "wheretocheck" : "Where102",
      "measurestobetaken" : "Measure102"
      },
      {
       ETC,ETC,ETC   
      }
    ]
```

I tried various ways but I always "receive" something like this (Which is not good):
[image]

This is my code:

```
for ( var counter : number = 0; counter < this.gbrumdatacoesplit.length; counter ++ )
 {
   this.coefilter = this.causesoferror.filter(coeelement => coeelement['code'] == this.gbrumdatacoesplit[counter]);
   this.coefiltered.push(this.coefilter);
 }
   console.log(this.coefiltered);
```

Comment: flter returns an **array** containing **all** the objects that match the predicate. Either get the first element of this array if it exists (assuming there should only be one), or use find() instead and test that it returns an object. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: It works, sometimes is easier than expected :)
Thank You very much

Answer (score 1):

If i understood correctly, you want to filter data by codes. here is the sample code

```
const data = [
  {
    "code": "004",
    "descr": "Descr004",
    "wheretocheck": "Where004",
    "measurestobetaken": "Measure004"
  },
  {
    "code": "101",
    "descr": "Descr101",
    "wheretocheck": "Where101",
    "measurestobetaken": "Measure101"
  },
  {
    "code": "102",
    "descr": "Descr102",
    "wheretocheck": "Where102",
    "measurestobetaken": "Measure102"
  }
];
const codes = ['004', '102'];
const filterData = data.filter(item => codes.includes(item.code));
console.log(filterData)
```

filter data would be

```
const filterData = [
  {
    "code": "004",
    "descr": "Descr004",
    "wheretocheck": "Where004",
    "measurestobetaken": "Measure004"
  },
  {
    "code": "102",
    "descr": "Descr102",
    "wheretocheck": "Where102",
    "measurestobetaken": "Measure102"
  }
];
```